# Unable to connect to maven repository when using proxy

Tags: java, maven

My machine is using proxy to connect internet. But I get the following error when running maven build command. And it works when I disable proxy. I don't understand why proxy matters here.

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project flink-dist_2.11: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.flink:flink-
dist_2.11:jar:1.7-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at 

    org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber:jar:1.7-SNAPSHOT:
 Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber:jar:1.7-SNAPSHOT:
 Could not transfer artifact 
    org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber:pom:1.7-SNAPSHOT from/to apache.snapshots (https://repository.
apache.org/snapshots): Remote host closed connection during handshake: SSL peer shut down incorrectly -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the settings.xml at ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml , more guidance here https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

in windows7 and above it would be c:\users\user_name\.m2

Answer (score 0):

Maven is trying to connect to a remote repository in order to downlod your project dependencies in its local repository. That's a network connection and obviously, your proxy configuration makes Maven fail in the attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Remote host closed connection during handshake: SSL peer shut down incorrectly :
This indicates that the server host that your are trying to achieve is down, verify first if the connection is well established and try again.

Answer (score 0):

May be try this by configuring Mavan accordingly for using the proxy server:- https://dzone.com/articles/how-get-maven-working-through

Answer (score 0):

I faced to the same problem at my work where we have `Windows` workstations and `NTLM2` proxy server with authentication.

The following solution works fine for me. The benefit of this solution is that it can work with Maven, Git, IntelliJ IDE as well.

**Reccomended steps you need to accomplish in order to have access via NTLM2 proxy:**

1. First you need to download, configure and run `Cntlm` proxy on your pc.
2. Start Cntlm on your localhost. This proxy will forward all your local unauthenticated HTTP/HTTPS requests to the company proxy as a authenticated requests.
3. Configure Maven, Git, IntelliJ, Eclipse, etc. to use your local proxy on `localhost:3128`. You do not need to configure authentication here.

**Details:**

1. Download Cntlm proxy from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cntlm/).
2. Type `cntlm.exe -H -d your_domain -u your_username`.
   It will ask your password. Enter it and Cntlm will give you the hashes, something like this:

   ```
   Password:
   PassLM          4E9C185932FER43543RWEFER33R4R34C
   PassNT          6E9F1254353RDR34RFSDWER3443RDC9A
   PassNTLMv2      43534RFWDWE3434RWFWER434C4FA224F
   ```
3. Edit / check your `cntlm.ini` file

   ```
   Username   <your-domain-username>
   Domain     <windows-donain-name>
   Auth       NTLMv2
   PassNTLMv2 <hash>
   Proxy      <proxy-host:port>
   NoProxy    localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.*
   Listen     3128
   ```
4. Start Cntlm with a simple script: `start-proxy.cmd`

   ```
   cd %CNTLM_HOME%

   rem verbose mode
   cntlm -v -c cntlm.ini

   rem verbose with logfile
   rem cntlm -v -c cntlm.ini -T %CNTLM_HOME%\nctlm.log

   rem test configuration
   rem cntlm -c cntlm.ini -I -M http://google.com
   ```
5. Stop Cntlm server: `stop-proxy.cmd`

   ```
   taskkill /IM cntlm.exe /F
   ```

**Then you can create two cmd files which change Maven configuration as per your flavour:**

6. `mvn-internet.cmd`

   ```
   call java8.cmd
   del %MAVEN_HOME%\conf\settings.xml
   copy %MAVEN_HOME%\conf\settings.xml.internet %MAVEN_HOME%\conf\settings.xml
   ```
7. `mvn-intranet.cmd`

   ```
   call java8.cmd
   del %MAVEN_HOME%\conf\settings.xml
   copy %MAVEN_HOME%\conf\settings.xml.nexus %MAVEN_HOME%\conf\settings.xml
   ```
8. `settings.xml.internet`

   ```
   <settings xmlns=...>
       <localRepository>...</localRepository>
       <proxies>
           <proxy>
               <id>my-proxy</id>
               <active>true</active>
               <protocol>http</protocol>
               <host>localhost</host>
               <port>3128</port>
               <nonProxyHosts>locahost</nonProxyHosts>
           </proxy>
       </proxies>
   </settings>
   ```
9. `settings.xml.nexus`

   ```
   <settings>
       <localRepository>...</localRepository>
       <mirrors>
           <mirror>
               <id>local-lalm</id>
               <name>local-lalm</name>
               <url>https://nexus.xxx...</url>
               <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
           </mirror>
       </mirrors>  
       <profiles>
           <profile>
               <id>use-local-repo</id>
               <activation>
                   <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
               </activation>
               <repositories>
                   <repository>
                       <id>LALM-global</id>
                       <url>https://nexus.xxx...</url>
                   </repository>
               </repositories>
               <pluginRepositories>
                   <pluginRepository>
                       <id>LALM-global</id>
                       <url>https://nexus.xxx...</url>
                   </pluginRepository>
               </pluginRepositories>
               <properties>
                   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
               </properties>
           </profile>
       </profiles>
   </settings>
   ```

**Do the same with Git**

10. `git-internet.cmd`

    ```
    call java8.cmd
    rem git config --global http.proxy username:password@localhost:3128
    git config --global http.proxy localhost:3128
    ```
11. `git-intranet.cmd`

    ```
    call java8.cmd
    git config --global --unset http.proxy
    ```

**Cunfigure IntelliJ**

12. Set up IntelliJ to use proxy on localhost:3128
13. Set up Maven in IntelliJ: change `Maven home directory` and `User settings file` configs.

After that you will use the same Maven configuration within IntelliJ and command line so everythink will work on the same way from IDE and comand line.

You can use your new cmd files to change between use or not proxy server on the fly.

This configuration takes 10 mins. and after that you can forgot this proxy issue.